# Spring3: How to register my own resource prefix/protocol

Tags: spring, resources

I would like to write an own Resource (from the core.io package) implementation for a custom resource prefix, e.g. "myprotocol:/root/test/foo.properties".

The original idea is to reference an Apache Sling resource path in the JCR repository for loading some properties file which then may be used by the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in the Spring application context, e.g.:

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="appConfig" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<bean id="appConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>jcr:/app/test/foo.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to implement this?

Thanks for your help!
Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving of resource paths is performed fixed way in getResource(String) method of the DefaultResourceLoader class that is a superclass for all application contexts.

One idea how the problem could be solved is to subclass the application context.

```
public class CustomXmlApplicationContext extends AbstractXmlApplicationContext {

    private final CustomResourceLocator customResourceLocator;

    @Override
    public Resource getResource(String location) {
        Assert.notNull(location, "Location must not be null");
        if (location.startsWith("custom:")) {
            return customResourceLocator.getResource(location);
        }
        return super.getResource(location);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Spring 4.3 `DefaultResourceLoader` now has an `addProtocolResolver()` method that allows you to supply an implementation of the `ProtocolResolver` interface that takes a String and returns your implementation of `ResourceLoader` if you are able to load resources identified by the String value.

Comment: Would like to add that implementing `ResourceLoaderAware` does even simplify the registration of your `ProtocolResolver`, see e.g. [this code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/7d3532e215b035081d92ee742a8c86ec5075ec91/spring-cloud-gcp-storage/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/storage/GoogleStorageProtocolResolver.java#L82-L91).